# Insert or update in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a simple table with 4 columns (ID (auto gen), ip,date,visits)

ex:

1,'10.10.0.10', '2017-03-01',1

I am looking for Insert or Update in SQLite which needs to check the ip & date column and if exists update visits +1 else insert a new row.

i can issue 2 sql but wanted to keep it in 1 sql.

Is this possible in SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

If you generate a uniqe index for IP and date you can use the [`insert or replace`](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) statement to achieve this in two steps:

1. Try to query the current number of visits for IP and date; set to 0 if record not found.
2. Execute the `insert or replace` for IP and date (I'm using named parameters in this example; you need to bind them to the appropriate values):

   ```
   insert or replace into Visits (id, ip, date, visits)
   values (NULL, :ip, :date, :visits + 1);
   ```

You can add a table contstraint to create the unique index like in the following example, or you use a separate `create unique index` statement:

```
create table Visits (..., unique (ip, date));
```

Addendum: There's even a possibility to update the number of visits in one query:

```
insert or replace into Visits (id, ip, date, visits)
    select NULL, :ip, :date, ifnull(max(visits), 0) + 1
    from Visits
    where ip = :ip and date = :date;
```