# Get row id on update

Tags: sqlite, upsert

Let's say I have a table of the following structure:

```
| name        | Type          |
| ----------- |:-------------:|
| id          | primary       |
| word        | unique        |
| frequency   | integer       |
```

To this table, I am doing inserts, when a duplicate occurs, I'll update the frequency column. Pseudo code looks something like this:

```
try {
    INSERT into WORDLIST word1
    id = lastInsertedId
} catch(Exception) {
    //if a duplicate happens
    UPDATE wordlist WHERE word = "word1"
    id = SELECT id FROM wordlist where word = "word1"
}
//save the updated/inserted id somewhere
```

The problem with the above code is that when a duplicate happens I am forced to do an extra select query to obtain the id of the updated row which is a performance buster and slows the app down for about 30%.

I'm open to other approaches but couldn't think of something better than this try/catch approach with an extra query

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: well, I can't show you an example without a large dataset, here's the code https://github.com/teamtnt/tntsearch/blob/master/src/Indexer/TNTIndexer.php#L385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `word` already has a unique index you can try to simplify your query by using [`insert or replace`](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE into WORDLIST word1
id = last_insert_rowid()
```

Note that in the conflict case a new rowid/ID is created and the old one is dropped. If you need to keep the ID you could resort to using a trigger, which may perform better than handling the special case in application code.

If all you want is implement a hit counter you can look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42556302/5794048

Comment: This would be perfect but I have some troubles with it: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 
wordlist ( term, frequency) values ("word", frequency + 1)
seems to fail saying that the column frequency doesn't exist. When a duplicate key constraint happens, I need to increment the frequency

Comment: @Nenad If I get this right this is sort of a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info); see my update.

Comment: yeah, you kinda right, I'll accept your answer because it answers the initial question

Answer (score 0):

The UPDATE statement cannot return data. If you need the ID, you need to run a SELECT.

Please note that any INSERT or UPDATE must check the `word` column for duplicates, so the SELECT will entirely run from cache. Any slowdown probably comes from running multiple changes with automatic transactions.

Additionally, relying on an exception to detect the duplicate will break down if there is any other error. Better check for duplicates first (which will not be any less efficient for the reason mentioned above):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT id FROM wordlist WHERE word = ?;
if found:
    UPDATE wordlist ... WHERE id = ?;   -- faster than word=?
else:
    INSERT INTO wordlist;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already tried this approach, but it's slower than the try/catch. The above code is way simplified of course just to point out the problem, the catch block checks if it was an integrity constraint  error and also handles other cases

Comment: just to explain my case a little bit more and why the above use case doesn't improve the performance as expected. If you have 100 words that don't exist in the table, you will run 100 times a SELECT and 100 times an INSERT. With the try catch approach, only INSERT happens, so when the table is empty, only INSERTs are hit and after the dataset grows, it starts to hit more UPDATES and SELECTs. So in some cases your approach would work better. It kinda depends on the dataset. But based on the average dataset, it seems the try/catch is faster

Comment: to make some more sense, it's an text indexer, that indexes for example million of text documents so even a small improvement saves a lot of time

Comment: I know that the UPDATE doesn't return data, but would it be possible to force the INSERT when it fails to return the ID of the row that failed?